# Why are only certain objects in my collection being written with writeObject()?

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I have created two applications, one "server" and one "client". My goal is to write Serializable objects that exist in the server application to disk, so that they can be accessed later. However, when I call writeObject() on the server, with the collection as the input, only part of the collection is written to a file. I am using Java RMI to invoke the creation of objects on the server.

The objects that *are* being written to file are created entirely with code in the server application. The objects that *aren't* are created by the server with some input from the client - but the server is doing all the work of creating and storing the objects.

For example, in the server application, I have these methods:

```
Class Server{
 HashMap<Listing> activeListings;
 int nextListingID=0;

 void createListing(ListingSpec lst)
 {
  nextListingID+=1;
  temp = new Listing(nextListingID, lst);
  activeListings.put(nextListingID, temp);
 }


 writeProcess()
 { 
  File f = new File("/activeListings.ser");
  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputSteram(fout);
  oos.writeObject(activeListings);
  oos.close();
  fout.close();
 }
```

I call `createListing` several times, sometimes initiated by the server and sometimes invoked via RMI by the client. I ensure that all of the objects I wish to write to disk are instantiated and exist in the server's `activeListings` collection. But then, when I call `writeProcess`, ONLY objects that were created *without* RMI are written to the disk in `activeListings.ser`. In fact - when I check the contents of `activeListings` after the `writeObject` command, those objects are gone from the collection!

I am new to RMI and distributed applications in general, so I feel like I am missing some fundamental rule about RMI method invocation. If all the objects are created locally, why aren't they all  being written? Furthermore, why are they disappearing from the collection itself?

Comment: Check the contents of your HashMap *before* invoking the `writeObject` method - chances are that these objects aren't there before you write either. If so, you likely have a problem in your implementation of the  `hashCode` or `equals` method.

Comment: That's what is puzzling me - they do appear to be in the collection before I call `writeObject`. For my own benefit, I printed the contents of the collection to the console to ensure I wasn't losing my mind, and they are there!

Comment: There is no [tag:rmi] in your question.